# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType - angular PWA

Tags: angular, service-worker

after adding @angular/pwa to my app

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project appName
```

I get error

> core.js:34469 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at registerNgModuleType

If I in my `appName.module.ts` remove from imports

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
  enabled: environment.production
})
```

app working again.

Angular.json is added

```
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "projects/tol5-admin-app/ngsw-config.json"
```

Here is my package.json

```
 "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.5",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.3.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.26.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "tslint-angular": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: @JoelJoseph I search and on only one place I use id... and try your solution, but nothing helps. Why this compiled ok and built for production without PWA added in module imports? I think the problem is directly in pwa

Comment: nasty nasty nasty error, This error really needs some explanatory message

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This often happens when you've mixed up `imports` and `declarations` in the pertinent module (or some other such mix-up). 
 You might for example have put a *component* in the `imports` array, where only *modules* should be 'declared'. 
The component should be in the `declarations` array.

Comment: In my case, I was missing the `@` infront of the NgModule decorator. As soon as I corrected it to `@NgModule` it worked.

Comment: Hello Jai, what other "mix-ups" that could happen?

Comment: How to find in which module wrong module imported for large application ?

Comment: I had the same issue, and realize I have installed the wrong version of Angular Language Service extension. My project had Angular 8 but using the extension of v12, so I downgraded the ALS extension from v12 to v0.8

Answer (score 59):

In my case this error occurred seemingly at random. One moment it was working, and the next moment it wasn't. Known working commits were also broken.

I had to delete `node_modules` and reinstall them which fixed the problem.

Comment: A similar thing happened to me as well. I uninstalled an npm module that I no longer needed, but left the import of that module intact in a component. Then `ng serve` stopped working with the error during app bootstrap. Deleting the `node_modules` folder and doing a fresh `yarn install` is what fixed it for me. I think it has something to do with how Angular does module caching in development mode.

Comment: It happends if you have update your application name and copy paste in to the another directory, if you missed something in between for your node_modules, you will be getting this error. For fixing this error, you need to removed node_modules directory and run the command npm install

Comment: I assumed this would work after upgrading angular from 8 to 10, but I am still receiving this error, anyone have any advice?

Comment: In my case I executed in yarn script in an npm project. So deleting node_modules and starting afresh solved it. Thanks waylander

Comment: Faced the same issue, and fixed it. Thanks @Waylander

Answer (score 27):

In my case, I was running Angular 8 and my project suddenly stoped working (I assumed after a VS code update v 1.56.2)

I resolved this issue by **deactivating** a VS Code extension called `Angular Language Service` and deleting the node_modules folder.

Then i run `npm install` and my project is working since.

My package json dependencies

```json
{
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "~2.5.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^4.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "core-js": "3.5.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "file-saver": "2.0.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.5",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.1.6",
    "ngx-progressbar": "2.1.1",
    "oidc-client": "1.10.1",
    "popper": "1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Same issue here, so you aren't using Angular Language Service anymore?

Comment: See my answer below for a fix that allows you to keep the latest angular language service for older versions of angular

Answer (score 12):

For me, this issue was related to the VSCode Plugin "Angular Language Service". I upgraded the plugin to the latest, and started getting this error. I am writing a new answer, because I still wanted to use the ALS so here are the steps to resolve it for people who are using ALS (latest) and an older version of angular in my case 8.

Basically what is happening is the new version of ALS uses the IVY engine which creates a bunch of files in node_modules that are not compatible with older versions of angular, so the below steps will fix that.

1. Upgrade to latest ALS (13.1.0)
2. Delete node-modules
3. Edit "Workspace settings" in VSCode and choose "Use legacy view engine language service"
   [image]
4. Run npm-install
5. Profit.

Comment: For anyone who deleted node_modules and it worked for a period of time only for the issue to reappear later, give this answer a try.

Answer (score 8):

in 2021 on 8 angular I faced this issue, just removed node_modules and reinstalled it - issue was solved.
so:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks. The only proposed solution that worked for me.

Comment: The issue seems to be deeper than that. As this works for a while, the error may appear again. In my case, the issue was resolved after deleting node_modules and running "npm i" again. However the issue repeated itself again. I re-did the same process many times, but the issue keeps coming back after it has worked for a while. Has anyone actually found the reason this may be happening, other than removing the "Angular Language Service" VS Code extention?

Comment: IMO it depends on the version of the current angular lib in the project and the version of the language service addon. You can try to test this issue from scratch with a clean project, test angular version, next add language service step by step

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This could happen when you have imported a wrong module inside `imports` array in module also. One time when working with a reactive forms, I had mistakenly added `FormBuilder` inside imports rather than `ReactiveFormsModule` and it gave me the similar error.

Looks like this error could come from multiple reasons.

Comment: How to find in which module wrong module imported for large application ?

Comment: I was importing a @injectable class in imports : [inyectable class(not a module)] and i got this error.

Answer (score 5):

disable any editor extension causing the problem. In my case it was angular language service extension for visual studio code, re-install node_modules and restart angular cli and editor.

Answer (score 5):

1. Disable **vs code**  extension **Angular Language Service**
2. remove the node modules( `rm -rf node_modules`)
3. re-install node modules using `npm i`

Comment: I noticed that the problem appeared after something was compiling modules in the background

Answer (score 3):

You should run this command to build your angular app `ng build --prod` and angular will show you the error detail.

In my case, I import wrong library from Angular Material.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/button/button.d.ts:22:22 -
> error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of ListeningModule, but
> could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/button) which
> declares MatButton has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not
> compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library
> is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the
> library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible
> with Ivy.

Answer (score 3):

On Angular 8,
I disabled Angular Language Service
however, rm-rf node_modules did not work, I just deleted normally on windows.
I had to run powershell as administrator then npm install then downgraded Angular Language Service Extention in vs code from 12 to v11.2.13.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occurred seemingly at random.I had to delete node_modules and reinstall them which fixed the problem.But opening the project runtime discount again has an error

Answer (score 1):

it happen to me in angular 8 after i move the project and rename the project folder name... the solution was the delete the node_modules folder and reinstall iy with "npm ci" (that use the package-lock.json)

Answer (score 0):

As told by jai, I got this issue when I added a component in the imports section.
Components should be in the declarations part. moving the SearchFilterComponent to declarations solved this issue.

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './admin-settings-menu-routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SearchFilterComponent } from '../dashboard/common/search-filter/search-filter.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
   SearchFilterComponent   //Should not be declared here
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AdminMenuModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix. Just make sure only components are declared in components array, only modules imported are in imports array and services should in providers array.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and  I have resolved . I find something in node_modules/angular/* , that means Ivy is work, so I disable it in
tsconfig.app.json

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Comment: VSCode angular-language-service use Ivy

Answer (score 0):

Try with npx ngcc

[Follow github link for answer](https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars/issues/190#issuecomment-598878096)